# Cannot find active sheet: TypeError: read properties of undefined (reading 'source')

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I'm trying to add the current date to a cell in column K when any cell in that respective row is changed.

I found this script and altered it for my situation so I can deploy it as a trigger:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (sh.getName() !== 'pipeline' || e.range.columnStart == 1 || e.range.columnStart > 10 || e.range.rowStart < 6) return;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 11).setValue(new Date())
}
```

As you can see I'm searching for tab named `pipeline`, which exists, it's the 3rd tab in my target sheet.
However, when I click the Google Apps Script Editor "Run" button I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'source')

[image]

Instead of editing the code, I also tried going to my target sheet `pipeline` and made some changes. When I then check the trigger itself I see that it's being executed but with errors:
[image]

I then inspect the errors (they're all the same) and see

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'columnStart')
> at onEdit(Code:3:48)
> [image]

I read multiple articles recommended by Rubén below, but none of them seems to address my issue (e.g. they address a mismatch in cell values, which I'm not checking for and using forms which I'm not using).

From what I can derive from the error, initially I thought the `e` parameter was not found, but `sh.getName()` check is passed, so `e` seems to be fine.

But I don't see why `e.range.columnStart` seems to fail.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If by "when I run the script" you mean that you click the **Run** button from the Google Apps Script editor toolbar, the error occurs because the script editor doesn't assigns an object to the function parameter. This is very comment problem that has being asked multiple times. By the other hand it's not clear if this is a bounded script or a stand alone script, among other missing details.

Comment: Searching [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined is:question isanswered:1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+properties+of+undefined+is%3Aquestion+isanswered%3A1) returns 4 answered questions. If you need fuerther help review these questions, if you still need need help, [edit] your quetion to add a brief but complete description of you Google Apps Script project including the steps to reproduce the error and the relevant parts of the bounded spreasheet, show what you have tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: By the way, this is an edge question as is about an online IDE and the error is related to JavaScript and to programming concepts. [so] has many, many times more questions about this error.

Comment: The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that is designed to run automatically when you manually edit the spreadsheet. In that context, the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e` is properly populated.
Do not run the code through the **▷ Run** button in the script editor. If you do, the event parameter `e` is not populated, causing the error you mention.

Comment: @doubleunary Thanks. I didn't just test the Run button. Also when I'm outside of the editor and work in the actual sheet to test, the trigger is fired and throws the errors that you see in the last screenshot. What is causing that?

Comment: The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). You should delete the [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) you have created. The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) of the "on change" trigger lacks the fields you are trying to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger list shown in the question tells that there is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that runs on every change to the spreadsheet. The [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) of this type of trigger lacks the `source` and `range` fields the code attempts to reference.

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs automatically when the spreadsheet is manually edited without installing any triggers separately. Its event object includes the necessary fields.

To avoid the issue you describe, simply delete the installable trigger you have created.